# Long text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to display a long text in a TextView. This is my XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="@string/text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/lorem" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image]
The long text doesn't fit. What do I have to change?

Comment: what do you want it to look like? do you want it to wrap and the textview's height to change?

Comment: Yes, I want the whole text to fit into the screen.

Comment: If you only want the Lorem Ipsum to fill the whole screen - what is then the purpose of the TableLayout? The possible answer(s) depend on this as well (should @string/text) be visible at all? It is tiny? etc.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: The first "Lorem Ipsum:" is @string/text. That all is just an extract, I really need a TableLayout.

Comment: What I wanted to point out is the shrinkColumns and stretchColumns attribute on TableLayout, that may be of help if e.g. the left column only is supposed to e.g. show a (small) number. Here the left column could shrink to make more space in the right one to show the full text there.

Comment: check http://zaidisoft.com/2012/06/28/how-to-create-scrolling-textview-in-android/ link. this is a fine solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="@string/text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/lorem" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: @WarrenFaith What should it be ;)

Comment: not sure, it just looks wrong ... but hey, I am not a native speaker so I might be mistaken :) @gtumca-MAC you ruined my gag :/

Comment: @WarrenFaith: It was just a sample text... are u android developer?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the style, that you want to achive: If Its okay to have multible-Lines you can just add in xml

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

or

```
android:lines="2"
```

If not you can allow to scroll it horizontally with

```
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just put in your xml `textview` this line

```
tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"
```